# transact sql function for alter multiple tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to create a Datamodel at work with 29 Tables. A lot of tables have the same colums like "version year". Now I was wondering if theres a way to create a function which would add these columns to a Table.

Is this possible with transact-sql for a MS SQL Server? Or dose someone have a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add columns to multiple tables in a single SQL statement, but you can easily create a multi-statement SQL that adds the columns to the desired table (copy-paste ftw!):

```
ALTER  TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN [Version year] int
ALTER  TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN [Version year] int
ALTER  TABLE Table3 ADD COLUMN [Version year] int
...
```

...and so on

Comment: thanks for your answer! I hoped to avoid copy paste but if its the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a column to all of your tables, then you can use the undocumented sp_MSforeachtable procedure, or some kind of dynamic sql generation and EXEC or sp_executesql.

You can select the column information from the sys.columns and sys.tables views.

Based on your requirements, these solution could be much more difficult than the copy-paste one.